# initialize array on calling an interface cannot be changed

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface takes (int[], int. int) that I cannot change

```
void foo(int[], int a, int b);
```

I would like to call it without having to initialize an array first. i.e. something like this

```
foo({1,2,3}, 1, 2)
```

Not

```
int [] a = {1,2,3};
foo(a, 1, 2);
```

I am using MSVC 2013. I tried the following for which compiler complains

```
foo( (int[]) {1,2,3}, 1, 2);
```

Comment: How does `std::vector.push_back` comes by with your question?

Comment: Take a `std::array` or `std::vector` (whichever fits your needs) and it will work fine.

Comment: Samaras and Chris, could you elaborate your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[]` as a parameter is equivalent to `int*`. So you can use the `data()` member function to return a pointer its buffer:

```c++
foo(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}.data(), 1, 2); // std::array can also be used
```

Note that `std::vector` deallocates its buffer when its destructor runs, which in this case is when the full expression in which the temporary appears is fully evaluated (at the `;`). So make sure to not hold a pointer to any of the elements beyonds their lifetime or else you will have a dangling pointer. Dereferencing said dangling pointer will yield *undefined behavior*.